# One hardlink is locked. How do I remove the other?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I have several executables in different directories that are hard links to the same data.

```
.
|-- file 1
`-- cache
    `-- foo.exe
`-- bar
    `-- foo.exe <-hard link to .\cache\foo.exe
`-- baz
    `-- foo.exe <-hard link to .\cache\foo.exe
```

If one of these is currently running, I can not delete the others. I execute `.\bar\foo.exe` and then try to delete `.\baz\foo.exe` I am told that the file can not be deleted. Killing the `.\bar\foo.exe` process is not feasible, as it is a long running and expensive task. But I really need `.\baz\foo.exe` gone, because I need the name for something else.

is there a way to break the link and get rid of `.\baz\foo.exe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *rename* `baz\foo.exe` (for example, to `deleteme.exe`), then delete it after the process exits.

You can move the file elsewhere too, as long as it stays within the same filesystem. (Within a single filesystem, renaming and moving are almost the same thing.)

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to work. I can have my cleanup script sweep un-delete-ables into a junk dir, and clean them up later.